# CSS multi level parent selectors

Tags: html, css

I want to select the first level `.box` of each one of these three `.box` siblings, but not their children `.box`(s). (Does this make sense?)

Here's my markup:

```
<div class="box">
    <div class="box">
        test
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div class="box">
        test2
    </div>
</div>

<div class="box">
    <div class="box">
        test3
    </div>
</div>
```

How can I perform this selection with CSS?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is not possible unless you specifically refer to the parent of the outer boxes somehow. For example, if you know that all of this is going to be inside `#foo`, then `#foo > .box` will do the job.

However, you *can* select boxes which are in another box with `.box > .box` or `.box .box`, so in this manner it might be possible to do what you need using the classic workaround of "undoing changes". For example, to turn only the outer boxes blue:

```
.box { background: blue } /* make a far-reaching change */
.box .box { background: transparent } /* then undo it partially */
```

Of course the inner boxes will still show the blue background of their parents, but you get the idea.

Comment: Well if that's the only way, that's the only way. Thanks so much for your help!

Comment: Specifying the parent - as in the #foo > .box example - is a powerful and elegant way to do this.  The desired .box elements must have a parent, even if it's <body>.

Comment: This was in the event that I could not edit the existing markup. I'd also like to add to the answer saying if you are using jQuery as a selector you can use `:not` to preform this selection: `.box:not(.box > .box)`

Answer (score 2):

The better way to select just the first ones is to use the `>` in your css selector so use it like this:

```
body>.box {
    css here
}
```